# Items not getting add into array

Tags: java

I have 3 classes for this program. I want to print out the total price of the items after shopping, but there is a problem with the output. Though each time shopping are different in the number of items, the output are all the same. Could you please help me to fix it?

Here are my code:

This is the first class:

```
public class LineItem {
   private String name;
   private int quantity;
   private double pricePerUnit;
   /**
   *
   */
   public LineItem(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) {
      this.name = name;
      this.quantity = quantity;
      this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;             
   }


   public double getCost() {
      return quantity*pricePerUnit;
   }


   public void setQuantity(int newQuantity) {
      quantity=newQuantity;
   }
}
```

This is the second class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ShoppingCart {
   /**
   *
   */
   private LineItem[] item;
   private int check;

   public ShoppingCart() {
      item = new LineItem[10];
      check = 10;
   }




   public void add(LineItem newItem) {
      int i = 0;

      while (item[i] == null && check != 0){
         item[i] = newItem;
         i++;
         check -= check;
      }

   }


   public double getTotalCost() {
      double totalCost = 0.0;

      for(int i=0; i< item.length;i++){
         if(item[i]!=null)
            totalCost += item[i].getCost();
      }
      return totalCost;

  }

}
```

This is the third class:

```
public class ShoppingCartTester{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      ShoppingCart singleItemCart = new ShoppingCart();
      LineItem item1 = new LineItem("Dove shampoo",1,4.52);
      singleItemCart.add(item1);
      System.out.println(singleItemCart.getTotalCost());

      //
      ShoppingCart typicalCart = new ShoppingCart();
      item1 = new LineItem("Dove shampoo",1,4.52);
      typicalCart.add(item1);
      LineItem item2 = new LineItem("apples",5,10.80);
      typicalCart.add(item2);
      LineItem item3 = new LineItem("avocados",5,20);
      typicalCart.add(item3);
      LineItem item4 = new LineItem("chocolate",1,4.25);
      typicalCart.add(item4);
      LineItem item5 = new LineItem("green onions",3,3.49);
      typicalCart.add(item5);
      System.out.printf("%.2f", typicalCart.getTotalCost());
      System.out.println();

}
}
```

I think the problem is in the add method, but i have no idea how to fix it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: May we have a look at some output?

Comment: This is the output I got: 4.52 4.52

Comment: It should be different numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Add method:

```
public void add(LineItem newItem) {
      int i = 0; <--- Problem begins

      while (item[i] == null && check != 0){
         item[i] = newItem;
         i++;
         check -= check;
      }

   }
```

Everytime you are calling `add` `i` is getting reset to 0.

Fix1:: To have a `list` instead of `array`. `Array` comes with a fix size which you might want to avoid.

Comment: So how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to maintain a global variable with current item in cart (noOfItems), 
So that while adding you can directly add new item

So instead of

```
public void add(LineItem newItem) {
      int i = 0;

      while (item[i] == null && check != 0){
         item[i] = newItem;
         i++;
         check -= check;
      }

   }
```

**use**

```
public void add(LineItem newItem){
    item[++noOfItems] = newItem;
}
```

or second way

> its better to create **[ArrayList](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)** instead of array of object

Comment: I cannot use ArrayList for this homework since I haven't learned that yet. For the one you first used it, could you please explain that for me/

Comment: use my add() method and declare a variable `int noOfitems = 0;` into the class